# Provide a different video depending on the screen size HTML

Tags: html, video, responsive

I would like to use a video as a background in a website, but I would like to provide a smaller a clipped version so mobile phones don't have to download full version and waste bandwidth. How could I do it?

I've tried the following, but the browser downloads both before showing only one. I would like the browser to download only one video

```
<video controls>
    <source src="b.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)">
    <source src="a.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen and (min-width: 801px)">
</video>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this for some reason: "Media query of the resource's intended media; this should be used only in a <picture> element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this example code below is doing what you want.
It uses JavaScript to check the device's **screen.width** and set's a URL for the `<video>` tag according to size. The video tag is accessed by its **id**. As a starting point, it has a fake/empty URL (later updated by code).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myvid" controls>
    <source src="nothing.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>

<script>

window.onload = (event) => { myFunction( event ) };

function myFunction( event ) 
{
  alert("Screen Width is: " + screen.width);
  
 let myvid = document.getElementById("myvid");
 
 //# if BIGGER THAN the 800 pixels
 if ( screen.width > 800 ) { myvid.src = "a.mp4"; }
 
 //# if SMALLER THAN or EQUAL-TO the 800 pixels
 if ( screen.width <= 800 ) { myvid.src = "b.mp4"; }
 
 //# load URL (for playback)
 myvid.load();
  
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. As I am using parcel I had to load an existing fake 1sg video instead of nothing.mp4

Comment: There is no need to pass an event down, 'myFunction' doesn't use it.

Comment: @Phoenix This particular _"Change video depending on..."_ situation doesn't need the event, but it's still good practice for future readers to see it with an event reference (so they can expand it for handling other situations such as _"Change video depending on which button was pressed"_ etc).

Answer (score 1):

Since there´s no other way to show/hide video at different resolutions, you can use JS or jQuery, try this solution (modify it according to your need)

```
var video = $('#yourVideoId');
    
var width = $(window).width();

if (width < 1200) {
    //It is a small screen
    video.src="yourVideoSrc_Small.mp4";
} 
else 
{
    //It is a big screen or desktop
    video.src = "yourVideoSrc_Big.mp4";
}

video.type = "video/mp4";
video.load();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Web browser inspector says ""Content-Type" HTTP de "text/html" is not compatible"